# Retrieve Distinct concat values from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, distinct, concatenation

I have an SQL table advert

```
id       name       cat
11       abc        ab
12       acb        ab, bc
13       abb        bcd
14       abcd       ad
15       acbd       de
16       abbd       ad
```

On using DISTINCT function I am getting an output like this

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat FROM advert;
```

Output:

```
ab
ab, bc
bcd
ad
de
```

WHAT changes do I need to make in my query for output like this

```
ab
bc
bcd
ad
de
```

Comment: I guess that the best solution would be to assign one category per row. I assume that your `cat` is a varchar

Comment: I would say wrong table structure. Never put several values into one field.

Comment: What is the maximum number of values that can be in a single column?

Comment: @mabe02 Yes its varchar...the problem is i juz have posted 3 columns it has about 25 coulmns...If i put one value per field then i have to copy these 25 columns twice or may be thrice for three cat values...

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz two or three...

Comment: @Ashish you should probably revise the structure of your tables as @Seb was suggesting. One suggestion could be to consider to create a `cat` table with all the details you don't need to repeat in you other 25 columns and then refer to the `cat_id`

Comment: @mabe02 yeah thank you it will be a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct trim(substring_index(substring_index(cat,',',n),',',-1)) as cat

from   t join (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) r
       on cat like concat('%',repeat(',%',n-1))
```

Comment: can you please help me for another query also (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991678/compare-value-with-comma-seperated-string-sql-php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your table structure and make it like this.

tblName

```
id    | name
11       abc        
12       acb       
13       abb       
14       abcd      
15       acbd       
16       abbd
```

tblCat

```
id          | name_id |  cat
some ids*       11        ab
                12        ab
                12        bc
                13        bcd
                14        ad
                15        de
                16        ad
```

In this way you can easily query and manage your data in your tables.

Comment: I have created table as you recommend....Can you tell me the query to join these two....Thanks...

Comment: select distinct cat from tblCat

Comment: that query would show your desired result. but if you want to join these two **select distinct b.cat from tblCat as b inner join tblName as a**

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data structure so you are not storing comma-delimited lists in columns.  That is the wrong way to store data in a relational database . . . as you can see by the problems for answering this simple question.  What you want is a junction table.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other peoples bad designs.  You say that there are only two or values, then you can do:

```
select cat
from ((select substring_index(cat, ', ', 1) as cat
       from advert
      ) union all
      (select substring_index(substring_index(cat, ', ', 2), ', ', -1) as cat
       from advert
       where cat like '%, %'
      ) union all
      (select substring_index(substring_index(cat, ', ', 3), ', ', -1) as cat
       from advert
       where cat like '%, %, %'
      )
     ) c
group by cat;
```

Answer (score 0):

First... I would create a statement that would turn all the rows into one big massive comma delimited list.

```
DECLARE @tmp VarChar(max)
SET @tmp = ''
SELECT @tmp = @tmp + ColumnA + ',' FROM TableA
```

Then use the table valued udf split described by this SO article to turn that massive string back into a table with a distinct clause to ensure that it's unique.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2837662/261997

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dbo.Split(',', @tmp)
```

Full code example:

```
if object_id('dbo.Split') is not null
    drop function dbo.Split
go
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
go
declare @t table (colA varchar(max))
insert @t select '111, 223'
union all select '333'
union all select '444'
union all select '777,999';

select  ltrim(rtrim(s.s)) as colC
from    @t t
cross apply
        dbo.split(',', t.colA) s
```